# How to use a negative of a numeric column's value in workflow

Tags: workflow, column, workflow-variable

I have a column named "How many month before the due date to inform the focal" which is used to know how many months before the due date I need to remind the focal to do his task.

The problem is: I need to multiply this value by (-1) and then use it (with nintex calculate a date action).

I'm using sharepoint 2007.

Comment: We have decided not to allow 3rd party product questions on this site to keep focus on SharePoint. You should ask this type of questions on Nintex related foras. If you think this Q is relevant for SharePoint as well as Nintex feel free to ask a mod to get this Q re-opened!

Comment: Essence of the question not as regards NINTEX, but/rather on work with sharepoint columns !!!

Comment: I have reopened the question, but you should make it more clear what you need help doing, then more people will be able to help you (and for the record i did not vote down Q)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple options in your Nintex workflow, you could use the calculate a date operation or do a math operation or do a combination of both.

Get the value of the coilumn in your math operation, multiple it by -1 and output it to a variable.  In your calculate date operation set the month to the value you calculated in the math operation and provide it with a date to calculate on and out put it to a new date time variable.

You can also create an Offset calculated column that simply =[Your Column]*-1 and use that in your workflow.

It isn't column related per se.

Comment: i use this option:" You can also create an Offset calculated column that simply =[Your Column]*-1 and use that in your workflow" . thanks!